# How Can I Echo Out Array Items In An Organzied Way?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, sorting, for-loop

I want to echo out the content of this array in a 1, 2 way

```
$arr = array("name", "john", "lastname", "doe", "age", "55");
```

so I wish for it to look like

```
name = john
lastname = doe
age = 55
```

And my code currently looks like this

```
for ($x=0;$x<count($arr)/2;$x++) {
        echo $arr[$x] . " = " . $arr[$x++];
}
```

But it does not work. The 2 elements of the variable have to be outputted within the same going through of the loop so I can't just concatenate them or something like that.

Comment: check out print_r https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Comment: foreach (array as key => value ) ... check out foreach https://www.php.net/manual/de/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Your Array should look like this : `$arr = array("name"=>"john", "lastname"=>"doe", "age"=>55);`

Answer (score 0):

Your array should look like this :

```
$arr = array("name"=> "john", "lastname"=> "doe", "age"=> 55);
```

and then you can go like this :

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
   echo $key , " = " , $val ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It just needs a couple of small adjustments:

```
for ($x = 0; $x < count($arr); $x+=2) {
  echo $arr[$x] . " = " . $arr[$x+1] . "<br/>";
}
```

1. Change the loop criteria so it'll get all the way to the end of the dataset.
2. Change the loop criteria so it'll increment `$x` 2 steps at a time, and ten just get the `+1` for the
3. According to your question, it appears you want a line break between each data item. If this is for a web application, use `<br/>`. If it's for command-line or text-based output, use `PHP_EOL`.

However, there are other possible approaches using `foreach` which might be considered more elegant, as shown in the other answers here.

---

BTW, if you could have a more structured array using associative key-value pairs insteading of relying on index patterns e.g. `array("name" => "john",  "lastname" => "doe", "age" => 55);` that would make your life easier in general, so if you have the freedom to make a change like that, I'd advise it.